# Override bootcamp minimum USB size?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-8, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to install 64 bit Windows 8 on my Mac Machine (Mountain Lion OSX) using a USB as a boot drive. For some reason bootcamp requires atlesst a 8GB USB. I however only have a 4GB USB. Is there any way I can override the 8GB minimum considering the size of the ISO is only 3.3 GB?

Comment: You could choose not to use Bootcamp I suppose.  My suggestion just go out and buy the $9.99 8GB drive.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not the price I have a problem with. It's the inconvenience.

Comment: Will Mac and Windows be on the USB drive, or just Windows?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why bootcamp insists on a larger USB pendrive is that windows 8 will not fit on a 4GiB volume.

I know that you already mentioned that your iso is 3.3GB. However installing windows is not just copying an iso. It will copy **and uncompress** files. Even ignoring optional files like the pagefile and the hibernate files (neither of which are on the iso) your actual i disk requirements will be in excess of 3.3GB.

That is not a problem as long as they do not exceed 4GiB. However a quick search shows that about 8GiB of space is needed after installation.

Disk space needed for windows 8: ([source](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=5))

- x32 (on the DVD 2,9 GB, after installation on the hard disk 6,6GB +)
- x64 (on the DVD 3,6 GB, after installation on the hard disk 8,2GB +)

Summary: It will simply will not fit on a 4GB volume.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only Windows will be on the USB drive, simply use the Windows 8 installer to install Windows 8 on the USB drive.

When the computer reboots, hold the `Option` key to choose whether to boot Mac or Windows.